# toggle class for height

Tags: jquery, css

In my project, I am trying to `toggle` the height of a div whenever the user clicks on the title bar, by giving the following properties such that only title bar appears(just like FB Chat).

**css**

```
.minimize{min-height:10px;max-height:50px;height:auto;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#chat-outline').toggleClass('minimize');
```

But I think because of already existing CSS properties of that div, the jQuery is not being assigned.

```
#chat-outline
{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 16%;
    height: 45%;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

The jQuery function works good for all the properties(display,background-color,color,border) but it cant assign only `height`.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uyanix/1/)**

**EDIT**: By the help of Sam3k solution, I came very close to the result

http://jsbin.com/uyanix/19/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#chat-outline`, it's probably taking precedence over `.minimize`. If older browsers like IE6 are not being supported you could probably do:

```
#chat-outline.minimize{min-height:10px;max-height:50px;height:auto;}
```

I wouldn't use `!important` as suggested above as it only targets certain browsers and it's more hacky. Try my suggestion as it might be a cleaner approach.

**Update**:

[jsbin.com/uyanix/27](http://jsbin.com/uyanix/27)

Comment: I agree with you to not to use !important. Its working but I dont know why the titlebar height is becoming zero. which is spoiling the design.

Comment: This is working fine in [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uyanix/17/) but not in my project. I am still trying If I didnt get it then I will post here.. Thank you for help :)

Comment: After trying to solve it and being failed I am posting the full code [here](http://jsbin.com/uyanix/19/) please check

Comment: Just a Note: Whenever I minimize, the blue title bar is becoming very thin. Its hard to click on it to restore the chat.

Comment: I find that if you use exact height (in pixels) for the title bar, the problem goes away. Here: http://jsbin.com/uyanix/27/

Comment: Yes it is working but unfortunately it will show blank space at bottom   in other resolutions (I think) because I am using height and width in percentages. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `!important` declaration to your height in the `minimize` class.

Comment: It is minimizing the title bar not `#chat-outline` anyway to do that?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to adjust the `min-height` attribute, or overwrite it in `minimize`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the following fix: http://jsbin.com/uyanix/14

The toggle you created was toggling the class as expected, but here's a way where you can insure the height of your title-bar and provide a more explicit means to switch between a small and large size

CSS Changes

Make the title a fixed height, then toggle between min and max heights.

```
 #chat-title
    {
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4B6C9E;
    }

    #chat-outline.minimize{height:5px;}    
    #chat-outline.maximize{height:100%;}



#chat-outline
{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 16%;
    height: 45%;

    min-height: 25px;  
    min-width: 200px;
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 300px;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Add max height to the toggle 2 classes using Jquery

```
$('#chat-title-name').on('click', function () {
               $('#chat-outline').toggleClass('minimize');
                 $('#chat-outline').toggleClass('maximize'); 

    });
```

Initialize the DOM div to maximized, this will get un-maximized later

```
<div id="chat-outline" class='maximize'>
```

Here's an example:
http://jsbin.com/uyanix/14

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .toggleClass() with CSS transitions then use MAX-HEIGHT and remove the height property completely. On the class you intend to append just set the max-height to a height you know you'll never reach. By doing this the container height will be controlled by the content (which to an extent is dynamic).

```
.container {
    display: block;
    background: #ff0000;
    max-height: 40px;
    -moz-transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.appended-for-height {
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

Here is an example utilizing CSS transitions with .toggleClass()
http://codepen.io/ChadR/pen/gpvWGE